# SQL-Oracle Error "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Tags: sql, oracle

I insert some value to sql Oracle.

My query in procedure is:

```
INSERT INTO CHAT_CUSTOMER(customerId, customerName, status, lastLogin, isAdmin)
VALUES (v_customerId, v_customerName, v_status, to_date(v_lastLogin, 'dd/MON/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), v_isAdmin);
```

And I run my procedure:

```
V_CUSTOMERID := '111';
V_CUSTOMERNAME := 'AAA';
V_STATUS := 'Busy';
V_LASTLOGIN := '08/AUG/2015 21:02:44';
V_ISADMIN := '1';
```

Then I receive error:

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
ORA-06512: at line 11
```

I have searched some topics relating to this, but those didn't solve my problem. I add "to_date" but it still doesn't work.

Is there anything wrong here? Please explain for me and help me to solve it.

Comment: Check your NLS_LANG settings. The August on your Oracle server may not be called August but something else

Comment: Just adding, select * from v$nls_parameters to check NLS_LANG settings.

Comment: What did you declare V_LASTLOGIN as?

Comment: @MarioAna it's date type

Answer (score 1):

You declared v_last_login as a date, then you are doing a to_date on it when you do the insert. Try and change it so that the declaration on v_last_login is a varchar2. Then see if it gives you the error still.

Comment: it's date type therefore I don't need to convert it by using "to_date". It's 
INSERT INTO CHAT_CUSTOMER(customerId, customerName, status, lastLogin, isAdmin)
VALUES (v_customerId, v_customerName, v_status, v_lastLogin, v_isAdmin);

Comment: Yes, but this will help you find out if the error is occurring in the initial assignment of the variable or in the conversion during the insert. I guess both ways will help you find exactly where the issue is occurring. Personally I much prefer letting the database do the conversion for me instead of using what I think the DB format might be.